# Reporting Web Application without SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have build a Reporting Web Application using ASP.NET and SSRS with SQL DB.

Below is my concern :

1. Report rendering is slower . I need to make the report faster. Does Crystal Reports or some other things helps me to make report faster? Please suggest
2. I have heard from the experienced people that SSRS deployment will be more complicated to deploy correctly compared to crystal reports?
3. Can we build the reporting engine without SQL DB ?
4. May i know the different technologies to build web based reporting engine which is faster, licensed free, easy maintainence...

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I also mentioned in my answer: question 4 and in a sense also question 2 are asking for opinions. I'd suggest to edit or remove them, it's not really a fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1, rendering times. You should investigate the cause for the slow rendering. SSRS is not particularly known for its blazing speed (specially with heavy aggregates and large numbers (hundreds) of pages, but should be fast if you use it just as what it is: a reporting tool. If you have problems, analyze the [ExecutionLog2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) to check if it's the query, the processing, or the rendering that's giving trouble - and optimize accordingly.

Ad 2, deployment. There are a few issues to pay attention to, but in general you should be fine. In any case your question as it stands is too broad for SO, and fishing for opinions. I recommend you search a bit more, and if you still have a question ask it in chat (subjective, opinions) or on SO (objective, practical questions).

Ad 3, no DB. You can connect [a multitude of data sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219.aspx) to a report, including object data sources.

Ad 4 "best". I suggest you remove this subquestion, because it's really a subjective question asking for opinions (this is not recommended, as per the stack overflow FAQ).

Good luck building your reporting solution!

Comment: Thank You Jeroen. I have edited the Ad 4 and i think now it makes sense . can you please tell me the different ways to build web based reporting engine which is faster, licensed free, easy maintainence...

Comment: Not to be mean, but: nope, sorry. This is way [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for Stack Overflow, where we tend to stick to shorter, practical questions.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to 3 => If you use crystal reports for instance, you can construct you own dataset in code and pass the dataset to crystal reports which will do the formatting. This way you can omit the need of an sql db.